# Hard disk speed is dropping badly

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-explorer, filesystems

My hard disk speed is dropped every time I move files in windows but in Ubuntu everything is fine

[image: here a pic of whats happening]

the max speed is near 50mb/s but its dropped as usual

Comment: You’re not moving but copying. That’s a very important difference. With an average file size of just ~45 KiB, most time will be spent seeking.

Comment: yes but it also happen on moving and this case I m copying file over 600mb

Comment: How long does the same operation take on both OS? Only because you don't see a chart in Ubuntu does not mean it does not slow down.

Comment: are you testing with a single large file, or many small ones? are you copying to the same partition, or a differant one, and is the destination on the same disk?

Comment: @eckes now Ubuntu 17 show transfer speed it constanly give 30mbs without drop

Comment: @FrankThomas ok it give me same result weather file is single large or small ones, moving in same partition is usually take no time but in my case it also take nearly 1min and then its done

Comment: there should be a difference between many small files and one large one. if there isn't, then the issue is not likely the disk itself. is your antivirus set to scan on disk write? that would likely rate-limit the write in the same fashion, and kind of blur out the additional operations associated with creating many new files (file system metadata updates, repositioning to sparsely populate sectors, etc).

Comment: @kartik copying a single large file would be much faster than copying thousands of tiny files. In NTFS the first part of the copy may be faster because of the caching but when the cache is full and begin to flush to disk then speed will reduce significantly. What's important is the total time to copy or the average copy speed

Comment: [Note, this may be opinion-based] Windows is & always has been absolutely appalling at copying files. The same task on Mac or nix would take seconds not minutes. Compare the simple task of installing an app, which is essentially a file copy from source to destination.